# exsheets and/or xsim: enumerate equations by exercises

Tags: equations, enumerate, exsheets

I am working with the `exsheets` (and `xsim`) package within a `scrartcl` document class. I want to create a sheet with Problems and their respective Solutions, but such that the equations within each problem are enumerated according to the Problem they are in (with same counter for the Problem and its respective Solution). So far (minimal example), this is what I have:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print = true}

\begin{document}

\begin{question} First exercise with equation
\begin{equation}
  a + b = 1
\end{equation}
\end{question}
\begin{solution} Solution to first exercise with equation
\begin{equation}
  a - b = 1
\end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{question} First exercise with equation
\begin{equation}
  a + b = 1
\end{equation}
\end{question}
\begin{solution} Solution to first exercise with equation
\begin{equation}
  a - b = 1
\end{equation}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

which yields,

[image]

Now, if I add the instruction `\numberwithin{equation}{question}` then I can reset the counter by Problem,

[image]

but instead, I would like something like this:

[image]

---

Edit: Thank to @cgnieder now I know `xsim` exists. If possible (or more convenient) I'd like to do the same in this package.

Comment: this would work in `exsheets`' successor package `xsim`.

Comment: @cgnieder thank for the information, I didn' know about `xsim`. From the manual, I know `exercise/within` reset the numbering according to the provided `counter`, do you know how to set such criterion to something like `exercise/within = {exercise}` (which is wrong)?

Comment: You probably need to `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\QuestionNumber{\CurrentQuestionID}.\arabic{equation}}` with exsheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an up to date tex distribution `\counterwithin` works out of the box using

```
\counterwithin{equation}{question}
```

`\counterwithin` is defined by the LaTeX kernel since April 2018 so no additional package is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print = true}

\counterwithin{equation}{question}    
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  First exercise with equation
  \begin{equation}
    a + b = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Solution to first exercise with equation
  \begin{equation}
    a - b = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  First exercise with equation
  \begin{equation}
    a + b = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Solution to first exercise with equation
  \begin{equation}
    a - b = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With older versions of `exsheets` you may need to do

```
\renewcommand*\theequation{\GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}\arabic{equation}}
```

---

Some time between March and May 2017 I published the package `xsim` as successor to `exsheets`. The latter only gets bug fix releases while `xsim` is actively developed and improved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}
\xsimsetup{solution/print}
\counterwithin{equation}{exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  First exercise with equation
  \begin{equation}
    a + b = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Solution to first exercise with equation
  \begin{equation}
    a - b = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
  First exercise with equation
  \begin{equation}
    a + b = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Solution to first exercise with equation
  \begin{equation}
    a - b = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thequestion.\arabic{equation}}` in addition to `\numberwithin{equation}{question}`.

**Edit** that was completely wrong. Sorry! `\numberwithin` also changes how the counter is displayed, as does `\counterwithin`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work; commands in different order but nothing. I'm shifting now to `xsim` package. If any, all comments are welcome.

Comment: `\numberwithin` is defined in `amsmath`.  I think that `\counterwithin` is better in this case; requires `\usepackage{chngcntr}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you're right, and the `\renewcommand` is completely unnecessary. But the question seems to have `amsmath` loaded. Using `\counterwithin` also worked without loading `chngcntr` (maybe some other package loaded it). Weirdly *everything* I tried seemed to work, both `\numberwithin` and  `\counterwithin`. I can't figure out why nothing worked for @snc92